# how to refresh an android listview

Tags: android, listview

I realize that similar questions have been asked before. My list is displayed using

```
setListAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.listlayout, names));
```

to refresh, previous answers have either been to use notifyDataSetChanged()  or  invalidate()
but to what !?  I don't appear to have anything to apply the method to.

Sorry if I'm being daft.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Store your ArrayAdapter somewhere. For example

```
adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.listlayout, names)
setListAdapter(adapter);
...
adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

Answer (score 1):

First you need to have a reference to ArrayAdapter:

```
ArrayAdapter adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.listlayout, names);
setListAdapter(adapter);
```

Then when you need to manipulate data you need to do it via ArrayAdapter methods add, insert, remove, etc.. When done you call `adapter.NotifyDataSetChanged()`.

Answer (score 0):

To the list adapter.

```
ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = (ArrayAdapter<String>)yourListView.getAdapter();
adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

Answer (score 0):

I like to declare my adapter as a member variable and call it off of that.  But since you're not, you can do this:

```
listview.getAdapter().notifyDataSetChanged();
```

This assumes that your ListView object is called listView.